# function that creates list of time and corresponding cos(t) value and plotting it

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Good day! I'm trying to make a function that takes in a stop time and frequency from the user and then returns the value of cos(t).
Using the value obtained from the function, I tried plotting it using matplotlib.
I've been encountering "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (10000,)"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

######################

def cos_wave(t,freq):
    freq = 1/t
    x = np.arange(0,t,.001)
    y = []
    for i in x:
        c = np.cos(i)
        y.append(i)
    return y

time = float(input("Enter stop time: "))
freq = float(input("Enter frequency in Hertz: "))
t = np.arange(0, time,freq)


fig, cosx = plt.subplots()
cosx.plot(t, cos_wave(time,freq))

plt.show()
```

Please help me so that i can take any kind of t (nano to milli to seconds) and i'm not entirely sure how to incorporate the frequency into the code because i once made this code work but it only showed 1 cycle.

[this is what i want to output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atSRL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Convert frequency (assuming you mean sampling frequency?) to time step (`dt`) and use that as the third argument for `np.arange`.

The `cos_wave()` function is not necessary. You can just call `np.cos` on an array of times to get the cosine value for every point.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

######################

# You don't need this function. Just use np.cos(t) to get the cosine wave you want
def cos_wave(t,freq):
    freq = 1/t
    x = np.arange(0,t,.001)
    y = []
    for i in x:
        c = np.cos(i)
        y.append(i)
    return y

time = float(input("Enter stop time: "))
freq = float(input("Enter frequency in Hertz: "))
dt = 1./freq
t = np.arange(0, time, dt)


fig, cosx = plt.subplots()
cosx.plot(t, np.cos(t), linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This works but only when I input time = 10 and frequency = 1000. I'm trying to input 0.01 as the time but it does not resemble a cosine wave. sorry for my english it's not my first language.

Comment: If you use `time=0.01` you are only going to get a small segment of the cosine curve (which has a period of `2*np.pi`), so it won't have the sinusoidal signal of a cosine that you would expect, but it is still the cosine function for that interval of time.